# Forming product of function of prime factors

Tags: list-manipulation, factorization

Given a list of numbers each containing 2 prime factors, I wish to make a list of the products of the logs of each factor. For example, given

L = {4,6,9}, I would like to form P = {Log[2]*Log[2],Log[2]*Log[3],Log[3]*Log[3]}.

FactorInteger seems like a questionable route since it would require some work to distinguish squares from numbers with two distinct prime factors.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Warning: Trying to force Mma to display its results in the way you like them is usually difficult and doesn't pay off

Comment: @belisarius: If you are suggesting that the best way might be a short program then I can accept that.

Comment: I do not see how this can be done without, in effect, factoring the number.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: No, that has to be done.

Answer (score 1):

You could try a couple of rules, but the heads of the elements in the output list will mix `Times` and `HoldForm`...

```
Map[FactorInteger,{4,6,9,15,25,33,49,51}] /.
   {{{p_,2}}->HoldForm[Log[p]*Log[p]],
    {{p_,_},{q_,_}}->Log[p]*Log[q]}
```

Comment: Alternatively: `{4, 6, 9, 15, 25, 33, 49, 51} /. n_Integer /; PrimeOmega[n] == 2 :> Times @@ Log[Flatten[ConstantArray @@@ FactorInteger[n]]]`

Comment: Actually this was better than what I had anticipated, thanks.